# Trying to create rules and fire at runtime using drool but not working

Tags: java, drools

```
package com.sample;


import org.drools.core.SessionConfiguration;
import org.drools.core.base.RuleNameEqualsAgendaFilter;
import org.kie.api.KieServices;
import org.kie.api.builder.*;
import org.kie.api.runtime.KieContainer;
import org.kie.api.runtime.KieSession;
import org.kie.api.runtime.KieSessionConfiguration;


import java.io.StringReader;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class Test {

    public  Test() {

    }

    public  void fireRules(Object fact) throws Exception{


        KieServices ks  = KieServices.Factory.get();
        KieRepository kr = ks.getRepository();
        KieFileSystem kfs = ks.newKieFileSystem();
        KieSessionConfiguration conf= SessionConfiguration.newInstance();

         String path ="test.drl";
       String drl = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(path)));
        kfs.write("../resources/com/sample/rules/simple.drl",ks.getResources().newReaderResource( new StringReader(drl) ));

        KieBuilder kb = ks.newKieBuilder(kfs);
        kb.buildAll();

        if (kb.getResults().hasMessages(Message.Level.ERROR)) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Build Errors:\n" + kb.getResults().toString());
        }

        KieContainer kContainer = ks.newKieContainer(kr.getDefaultReleaseId());

        KieSession kSession = kContainer.newKieSession(conf);


        kSession.insert(fact);
        Test t = new Test();
        kSession.insert(t);
        
       System.out.println(kSession.fireAllRules());

        return;
    }


}
```

The above function is not firing the rules

rule "Rule 01"
when
eval( 1==1 )
then
System.out.println( "Rule 01 Works" );
end

The above is rule file.

I want to define the rules at runtime, but the above implemented code is not firing the rules. Is there any other method to create and deploy the rules .

Thanks in advance

Comment: So what're the errors?

Comment: No errors just rules are not fired

Comment: What happens when you spin up your IDE debugger and step through it?

Comment: can't figure out anything through debug mode,

Comment: Well by debugging can you confirm that it read the file as expected, wrote it to the correct location, built the rule successfully, etc? Because we don't have access to your system and setup.